# How can I download the HTML code from a website in an Android app I am writing?

Tags: java, android, html

I've searched everywhere, but I can not find a good .java file that downloads the HTML code of a website, and puts it into a String on Android.
I've tried using apps that import Apache jar software, but I can not get it to work.

The following are the Apache java files I have imported that don't work.

```
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext;
import org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpContext;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
```

Please help me.

I would like to download the HTML code for "http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=AAPL"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use URL objects and read data:

```
URL oracle = new URL("http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=AAPL");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
new InputStreamReader(oracle.openStream()));
StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
String inputLine;
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
    sb.append(inputLine);
in.close();
String data=sb.toString();
```